# Texture access in vertex shader (GLSL 1.2) allowed?

Tags: glsl, textures

I am trying to port a geometry shader back into an OpenGL 2.1 (GLSL 1.2) vertex shader.
After having replaced all code the compiler complained about, it gave me another error:

> Too many vertex shader texture samplers

So I queried GL for the allowed maximum and this what I got:

> GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 0
>   GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS_ARB: 0

This probably means that there are no textures allowed in the vertex shader.

Is this only a limitation of my hardware/driver or is it required by OpenGL2.1/GLSL1.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having successfully used vertex texturing on OpenGL 2.1 hardware, I can confirm that this is a mere hardware/driver limitation. Those constants wouldn't make much sense if OpenGL 2.1/GLSL 1.20 would completely disallow the possiblity of vertex textures in the first place.

**EDIT:** As a more objective proof of the above, the [*OpenGL Shading Language 1.10 Specification*](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf) (corresponding to OpenGL 2.0) says in section *8.7 Texture Lookup Functions*:

> Texture lookup functions are available to both vertex and fragment
>   shaders.

And the [*OpenGL 2.0 Specification*](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec20.20041022.pdf) itself says in section *2.15.4 Vertex Shaders - Shader Execution*:

> Vertex shaders have the ability to do a lookup into a texture map, if
>   supported by the GL implementation. The maximum number of texture
>   image units available to a vertex shader is
>   `MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`; a maximum number of zero indicates
>   that the GL implemenation does not support texture accesses in vertex
>   shaders.

Comment: `Those constants wouldn't make much sense ...` I use GLEW and therefore cannot tell if they are from a later version of OpenGL where they would make sense. But if you can confirm having used textures in GLSL1.2 vertex shaders, then it is obviously a driver issue.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the effort. I must admit I was too lazy to look into the specs (or I just had not enough time to do so).